# Codeigniter Printing Query Results

Tags: codeigniter

Simple question but I don't know why it is not printing correctly or working as expected. I have this in model (works because when I print_r($result) it shows data:

```
function get_latest_entries()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('property');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

And for controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $resultSet['properties'] = $this->propertymodel->get_latest_entries();
    $this->load->view('home', $resultSet);
}
```

In the view I want to iterate over the array (the table has description, city, address columns):

```
<?php
foreach($resultSet as $item)
{
    echo $item->city;
    echo $item->description;
}
?>
```

I am getting two records on home page where am displaying the results as above:

> Severity: Notice 
>   Message: Undefined variable: resultSet 
>   Filename: views/home.php 
>   Line Number: 16

And

> Severity: Warning 
>   Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
>   Filename: views/home.php 
>   Line Number: 16

Comment: use $properties instead of $resultSet

Comment: put it as an answer @ShayanHusaini so I can mark it as one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$properties` instead of `$resultSet`

Answer (score 2):

use this... you are passing `$properties` to your view and not `$resultSet`..

```
<?php
       foreach($properties as $item) // use properties
       {
        echo $item->city;
        echo $item->description;
       }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem in your code.
-you have returned data as array of arrays and you are trying to access as an object,
-and the second one is,you have passed properties variable to view and you are accessing resultSet.
-so here is your code in view which contains errors

```
<?php
foreach($resultSet as $item)
{
    echo $item->city;
    echo $item->description;
}
?>
```

-And the Correct version of your code is here...

```
<?php
foreach($properties as $item)
{
    echo $item['city'];
    echo $item['description'];
}
?>
```